# How to establish trilinear coordinates of the isoperimetric point $X(175)$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

The [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) lists X(175) as the *isoperimetric point* and that its trilinear coordinates are $-1 + \sec \frac{A}{2} \cos \frac{B}{2} \cos \frac{C}{2}$.

I have, however not been able to find a proof of this. Can someone provide the proof?

Answer (score 2):

We just need to read a few lines of the Wikipedia page about the [isoperimetric point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_point) to be convinced of the following fact: given the circles $\Gamma_A,\Gamma_B,\Gamma_C$ centered at $A,B,C$ and going through the projections of the incenter on the triangle sides, there are two circles simultaneously tangent to $\Gamma_A,\Gamma_B,\Gamma_C$. If $\Gamma_A,\Gamma_B,\Gamma_C$ lie inside the larger one (outer Soddy circle), the centre of the outer Soddy circle is a isoperimetric point. It is not difficult to show that the isoperimetric point, if exists, is unique, then we just need a bit of trigonometry$^{(*)}$ and/or circle inversions to locate the centre of the outer Soddy circle, i.e. to find its trilinear coordinates.

Guide to $(*)$: perform a circular inversion with respect to a circle centered at the tangency point $P$ of $\Gamma_C$ and $\Gamma_B$ having radius $R^2=(s-c)(s-c)$. That brings $\Gamma_B$ and $\Gamma_C$ into two parallel lines and $\Gamma_A$ into a circle tangent to both lines. The involved lengths in the new configuration just depend on $a$ and $r\cot\frac{B}{2}\cot\frac{C}{2}$. Translate the image of $\Gamma_A$ to find the inverse of the outer Soddy circle and consider a diameter of that circle that goes through $P$. Take the inverse of the endpoints of such a diameter to get a diameter of the outer Soddy circle, then compute the distance of the midpoint of such a diameter from the $BC$-side.

Comment: I know what is the isoperimetric point and I know the fact you state. I am asking for the proof for the trilinear coordinates themselves. What is this "bit of trigonometry" that you refer to? That is what I am looking for.

Comment: @rityzmon: I added a walkthrough to find the trilinear coordinates through circle inversion.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio You might be interested by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4676851/305862) of mine to a question dealing with secret agent $X(175)$.